# arabic tcolorbox for definition

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox, polyglossia

I have an error with this tex files, how to improve it ?

```
Runaway argument?
{
! Paragraph ended before \tcb@theo@label was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.79 \begin{definition}{}{}
```

thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titleps}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem
  []% init options
  {definition}% name
  {تعريف}
  % title
  {%
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
  }% options
% {def}% prefix



\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1,AutoFakeSlant=-0.03]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\begingroup \renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\words{chapter}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother
\titlecontents{lsection}
  [2.3em]{\LARGE}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-3em}}
  {}
\titlecontents{lsubsection}
  [4.6em]{\LARGE}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-3em}}
  {}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \words{chapter}}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{-10pt}




\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
الأول\or
\else
I need more words\fi}

\makeatletter

\makeatother

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\begingroup \renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\words{chapter}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\parindent=0mm

\begin{document}
\chapter{واحد}
\section{ح}


\section{حاول}

\begin{definition}{}{}
ليكن
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented in chat by [Ulrike Fischer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56201933#56201933) if you remove the comment before `{def}` in the last line of:

```latex
\newtcbtheorem
  []% init options
  {definition}% name
  {تعريف}
  % title
  {%
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
  }% options
{def}% prefix
```

you get an output (no idea if it's correct) (compiled with `xelatex`).

[image]

Comment: please how to obtain the numeration of definition with respect to the section for example 1.2 not 1,2,3 ,...

Comment: please @Rmano have you an idea ?

Comment: as @skillmon told you add `number within=section` in the option of the `\newtcbtheorm` (between the brackes where it says `%init options). I suggest reading the manual...

Comment: thank you very much it works !@Rmano